# Returning a Completable/Observables but checking is first - Flatmap?

Tags: java, android, reactivex

My Reactive knowledge is very basic and I was wondering what the right way would be if I like to return an observable from a function which is using an observable. I wanna extend the observable which I am calling with a check.

In my example, I think it is a lot of code for not much. I think I would also need to worry about the disposable of the inner observable. Do I?

```
public Completable updateUserPhotoURL(Uri photoURL, UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates) {
    return Completable.create(emitter -> {
        if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
            emitter.onError(new Exception("Firebase User is not initiated"));
        }

        RxFirebaseUser.updateProfile(mFirebaseUser, profileUpdates).complete()
                .subscribe(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        emitter.onComplete();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        emitter.onError(e);
                    }
                });
    });
}
```

What would be the right (more elegant) way of doing so?